# Leaflet Initialization is strange using jquery mobile pagecreate-event

Tags: initialization, leaflet

I'm having a hard time initializing a leaflet map in fullscreen in a jquery mobile project.

When I init the map from a $(document).on('pagecreate')-event the map starts as a very small layer sitting on the left top of the browser, and if I resize the browser just a little, the map pops into fullscreen and stays there.

On the other hand, when i init the map from a window.onload-event - everything inits perfect.

As i understand it using pagecreate is preferable, so i wanna use it.

**aspx:LeafletLoad.aspx**

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="LeafletLoad.aspx.cs" Inherits="RadikaleNu.LeafletLoad" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

    <title>Leflet load</title>
    <link href="Content/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/leafletload.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Javascript libraies -->
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/leaflet-src.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/leafletload.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <div data-role="page" id="MapPage" >

            <div role="main" class="ui-map">
                <!-- Map -->
                <div id="map"></div>

            </div>   

        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript: leafletload.js**

```
var map = null;
var osm = null;


//This works perfectly - the map starts fullscreen
/*
window.onload = function () {
    InitMap();

};
*/

//This works not so perfectly - the leflet map starts very minimized in the top left corneruntil browser resize.
$(document).on('pagecreate', function(){  
    InitMap();
});

function InitMap() {
    // set up the map
    map = new L.Map('map');

    osm = new L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.stamen.com/toner/{z}/{x}/{y}.{ext}', {
        subdomains: 'abcd',
        minZoom: 0,
        maxZoom: 20,
        ext: 'png'
    });

    // start the map in Copenhagen, Denmark
    map.setView(new L.LatLng(55.682665, 12.536639), 9);
    map.addLayer(osm);
}
```

**CSS: leafletload.css**

```
body { 
    margin: 0;
}

#map {
    height: 100%;
}

.ui-map {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0 !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> On the other hand, when i init the map from a window.onload-event - everything inits perfect.

You'll want to use onload. The gist of it is that events like `pagecreate` and `ready` (also known as `$(function(){})` fire when the page's content is loaded but the page isn't laid out - your browser doesn't know yet what size the map will be. Leaflet needs that size in order to draw the map, and since pagecreate doesn't let it know that, it draws a tiny, cropped map as you see currently.